# NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication when trying to connect to a TFS repository from jfrog

Tags: git, tfs, bower, artifactory, artifact

I am trying to connect to one of the TFS repositories we have as a bower repository in Artifactory, we are using one of our repository code as dependency in bower.json. It was working fine when we accessed the TFS repo from private bower, as we switched to Artifactory, we are unable to connect to TFS

steps followed :

1. added a VCS repo, gave proxy details as well.
2. added credentials to access repository.

Error received :

```
(o.a.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator:207) NTLM authentication error: Credentials
cannot be used for NTLM authentication:
org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you mean you want to use TFS as Remote Repository like this article mentioned: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VCS+Repositories? Are you using NTLM authentication setting on TFS Administration Console? Do you try to switch authentication settings from NTLM to Negotiate (Kerberos)?

Comment: I am using 4.7.5 jfrog version , I was just passing the proxy and in advanced tab , passing credentials (uid/pass) to connect to repository . I haven't switched authentication to negotiate kerberos . When we were using private bower , we were able to access repository ,but not from artifactory

Comment: Please check whether you Proxy definition is set as this article https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Proxies, and try to switch authentication settings from NTLM to Negotiate (Kerberos) to see whether it works.